# border is appending to image when I'm trying to save edited image on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js to develop an image editor through which user can scribble, text, sign and perform scaling and rotate operations. To save the edited image on canvas, I'm using the following function. But when saving that image, a black border is appending to image everytime. saveAjaxCall is a function which sends an AJAX call to save the image on server. May I know where I'm doing mistake.

```
canvas.discardActiveGroup().renderAll();
var objs = canvas.getObjects().map(function(o) {
    return o.set('active', false);
});
var group = new fabric.Group(objs, {
    originX: 'center', 
    originY: 'center'
});
saveAjaxCall(group.toDataURL());
group._restoreObjectsState();
```

Comment: Try replace `saveAjaxCall(group.toDataURL());` to `saveAjaxCall(canvas.toDataURL());`

Comment: my canvas size is 900*600px whereas the image on canvas size is 1500*1200px. If i do canvas.toDataURL(), only visible portion of image on canvas is getting cropped and saved. I'm losing remaining part of image

Comment: Why you not increase the size of canvas?

Comment: This is an application which will be used on different devices. canvas size differs from device to device. It is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
canvas.discardActiveGroup().renderAll();
var objs = canvas.getObjects().map(function(o) {
    return o.set('active', false);
});
var group = new fabric.Group(objs, {
    originX: 'center', 
    originY: 'center'
});
canvas.setWidth(1500);
canvas.setHeight(1200);
canvas.renderAll();
saveAjaxCall(canvas.toDataURL("png")); //default is jpg
group._restoreObjectsState();
canvas.setWidth(900);
canvas.setHeight(600);
canvas.renderAll();
```

Comment: canvas is getting cropped. Not the whole image is getting saved.

Comment: It's more easy if you post a jsfiddle